# CSS - Entire section disappears when re-sizing page

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm trying to add some media queries to my home page. When I resize the page an entire section gets cut off. The section is directly under the header and includes a background image with an image on top of it which is also an `a` tag. There's a small strip section (.showreel) at the foot of the section which also disappears.

This is the CSS for the section -

```
/* HOME PAGE */

section#home {

    height: 400px;

    background: url(../images/homepagemain.jpg) center center no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    background-position: center;
    overflow: hidden;

    position: relative;
}

#agencyimage {

    position: absolute;
    margin: 0;
    top: 40%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

}



.showreel {
  height: 50px;
  max-width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: black;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 0 30px;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.showreel, .showreel > div.seemore {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    flex:1;
}
.showreel, .showreel > div.seeour {
    justify-content: flex-end;
    flex:1;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.showreel p {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 10px;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.showreel i {
  color: #ffffff;
}

.seemore  {
  margin-left: 30px;
}


.seeour i {
  margin-right: 30px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<section id="home">

        <a href="agency.html"><img src="images/AGENCY-BUSINESS.png" id="agencyimage" style="width: 150px; height: 250px;"></a>

        <div class="container showreel">
            <div class="seemore">
                <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
                    <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x" style="color:#fff"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-chevron-down fa-stack-1x" style="color: #000000;"></i>
                </span>
                <p>SEE MORE</p>
            </div>
            <div class="seeour">
                <p>SEE OUR SHOWREEL</p>
                <i class="fa fa-play-circle fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

For my media queries I've put this -

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  div.container {
    float: none;
    margin: 0 20px 0 20px;
  }

  div.column {
    float: none;
    width: 50%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) { 


  header {
    float: none;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
  }

  nav {
    float: none;
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
  }

  nav a {
    display: block;

  } 



  section#home {
    float: none;
    height: auto;
    background-size: 100%;
  }

  section#home a {
    position: relative;
  }
```

I think this may have something to do with the position absolute / relative styling but I can't figure it out. I've tried all kinds of variations but nothing - there's obviously something fundamental that I'm missing but can't figure it out. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: I think some html would help. Maybe the problem is section#home height:auto

Comment: Create a demo using your css and html. Would make it easier for anyone who wants to help you.

Comment: You need to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @DanieleFois html now added.

Comment: You still don't have all the relevant HTML.  You mention `.showreel` in the question, but there's no HTML with a class of showreel...

Comment: try to set some fixed height on section#home

Comment: @cale_b First div under the a tag - "container showreel".

Answer (score 2):

What happens is normal. For the breakpoint of 480 pixels and lower you change the height of `section#home` to `auto` but this gives height `0` to this element because inside you position elements with `position:absolute`. In conjunction to that you have `overflow:hidden` for `section#home` so any content will be in fact hidden.

You can set a fixed height to `section#home` or change the `position:absolute` to `position:relative` or `position:static` for the inner elements and continue the development from that point.

Comment: Not necessarily. Depends on what you want to achieve. If there is reason to set the `height` to `auto` find the elements inside `section#home` with `position:absolute` and change their `position` to `static` or `relative`. For example  `#agencyimage` is such an element. When you do that, review how it looks and continue the development and modifications from that point.

Comment: The whole section is still disappearing, I've tried all the different ways recommended. Very strange.

Comment: Create a demo on jsbin.com to review it there. Maybe something else affect it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're giving section#home height:auto.

Set a fixed height on section like this:

```
section#home {
   height:400px;
}
```

Comment: No that's not doing anything - I'm convinced its to do with the position style rules but can't figure out what or how to overcome.